# loop through 'distinct' values and ignore duplicates - javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm completely rewriting this question to explain it better,

i have a list of objects as shown in the image.

[image: screenshot of console.log(point) as in the code below]

These all have the property statusCode: 62467 but the journey property goes like: 0,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4

i want to loop through these objects and return the FIRST of the duplicated objects with the same journey number.

So i want to return the bold objects: **0**,**1**,**2**,**3**,3,**4**,4,4,4

```
    $.each(points, function (index, point) {          
                    for (i = 0; i < journeyNumber.length; i++) {
                          if (point.k.journey === journeyNumber[i] && point.k.statusCode === '62467') {
                                console.log(point);
                                      latlngs.push(point.j.aa.k);
                                      latlngs.push(point.j.aa.B);
                          }
                     }
    });
```

the screenshot is the log of console.log(point), so ideally i would like another loop inside which returns only the first object of the same journey number.

hope this makes sense and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You can track which numbers have already been dealt with, and, on finding duplicates of them, skip them.

```
var already_seen = []; //container for logging unique values
$.each(points, function(index, point) {
    if (already_seen.indexOf(point) !== -1) return; //if already in container, skip
    already_seen.push(point); //log unseen values in the container
    for (i = 0; i < journeyNumber.length; i++) {
        if (journey === journeyNumber[i] && statusCode === '62467') {
            latlngs.push(lat);
            latlngs.push(lng);
            console.log(journey)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you but it still hasn't worked, console.logging already_seen.indexOf(point) is giving the following: 

-1 
0 
(10) -1
1 
(7)-1 
2 
(88)-1 
3 
(52)-1 
3 
(53)-1 
4 
(78)-1 
4
the number in bracket is how many times it was repeated

Answer (score 0):

How about making use of [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var unique = [];
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
$.each(points, function(index, point) {
    for (i = 0; i < journeyNumber.length; i++) {
        if (journey === journeyNumber[i] && statusCode === '62467') {
            latlngs.push(lat);
            latlngs.push(lng);
            unique.push(journey)
        }
    }
    console.log(unique.filter(onlyUnique));
});
```

Comment: Thanks this does work, however the journey is actually point.k.journey, which is a json property, i've edited my code to the real code so it makes sense, (i changed it before to make it easier to understand but realised it's caused a bit of confusion) thank you for your time!